# getting RGB data from pixels on an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

So, to begin I'm starting a project with python that allows for it to grab each individual pixel from an image, and then print the color. However I am trying to begin grabbing each pixel by finding the y and then adding 1 onto x until we hit all the pixels on the y axis.

```
    # Importing Image from PIL package
    from PIL import Image
    
    # creating a image object
    filename = "pixels.png"
    im = Image.open(filename)
    
    #finding the size of the image
    fs = im.size
    fs_x = fs[0]
    fs_y = fs[1]
    print(fs_x, fs_y)
    
    #converting the color to RGB
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    any = rgb_im.getpixel((25, 25))
    print(any)
    
    x_start = 0
    
    if x_start != fs_x:
        x_start = ++x_start
        print(x_start)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please detail the problem you are encountering and the solutions you have attempted. Then we can help you deal with the specific problems.

Comment: Python is not C/C++ and it doesn't have `++`

Comment: simpler `fs_x, fs_y = im.size`

Comment: if you want to visit all pixels then you have to use loop - `for`-loop or `while`-loop. You can't do it using `if`. - i.e `for y in range(fs_y): for x in range(fs_x): pixel = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))` - It seems you have to learn basis of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn loops - `for` and `while` - because you can't do it with `if`.

```
from PIL import Image
    
filename = "pixels.png"
img = Image.open(filename)
    
width, height = img.size
print('width :', width)
print('height:', height)

rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        pixel = rgb_img.getpixel((x, y))
        #print(pixel)
        r, g, b = pixel
        print(f'| R: {r:3} | G: {g:3} | B: {b:3} |')
```